# check_box_tag prints all object info to form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two Models with a has many through relationship, and I'm trying to get the form to work properly. I followed the Railscast [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2qwV0B9yfU) for it, and I'm also looking at the API dock on it [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag).

The code in question is this in my form:

```
<%= Region.all.each do |region| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'religion[region_ids][]', region.id %>
  <%= region.name %><br />
<% end %>
```

It properly puts out the checkboxes and the names of the regions, but it also prints all the info on each region.[image]

Can anyone tell me why it's doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the first line of your form: `<%= Region.all.each do |region| %>`. It should not have the equal sign `=` in the opening erb tag. So change the opening from `<%=` to `<%`, as follows:

```
<% Region.all.each do |region| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'religion[region_ids][]', region.id %>
  <%= region.name %><br />
<% end %>
```

The reason this happens is when you use the equal sign, it will attempt to display the output of the line. And in Ruby the `.each` method always returns the original array, which is why you are seeing all that extra info.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: No problem! Happens all the time